# How to distinguish between two sources in JSPlumb

Tags: jquery, html, svg, jquery-svg, jsplumb

Im creating a gui  questionnaire creator using JSPlumb and some of the answer types are yes/no.
I'm trying to find out which connector stems from the yes source and which connector stems from the no source once jsPlumb.getConnections() is called.

If you see the image below the green connection on the question "Is today a weekend" represents a Yes and answer. I can find out the source and destination of both the yes and the no but im not sure how to tell which one is which.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do the above but its a little dirty.

Get all connections and for each one get the connections endpoint html.

```
var outerHTML = $(this)[0].endpoints[0].canvas.outerHTML.toString();
```

From here check the html to see if it contains either the red or green colour set earlier.

If somebody knows a better way please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set different scope for the connections, as in your case two scopes "yes" and "no" during connection creation with [**scope**](http://jsplumb.org/apidocs/files/jquery-jsPlumb-1-3-16-all-js.html#Connection.scope) option. While querying you can specify the required scope along with source or target element if needed, refer [API DOC](http://jsplumb.org/apidocs/files/jquery-jsPlumb-1-3-16-all-js.html#getConnections).

Example code:

```
var con=jsPlumb.getConnections({
        source:$(this),
        scope:"no"
});
```

Note that `con` is array of connections. Based on the variable `con` you can get the target innerHTML.

```
var HTML = $('#'+con[0].targetId).html(); // For single connection
```